# D3 Typescript SVG append not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, svg

I've been able to get numerous different objects to populate correctly on the DOM using D3 and Angular.
Angular 4.4.6
D3 4.13.0
types/d3 4.12.0
My problem is the SVG will populate correctly the first time but will not update either through a button or through interval duration. I've tried running this outside of angular using NgZone and that did not work either. I have attached my code same running in Stackblitz and have also linked the "working" copy that is in JavaScript.  Here is the link in Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-df5mk8

```
update() {

    this.cdr.detectChanges();

    var svg = d3.select(this.root.nativeElement)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('height', 600)
        .attr('width', 600)
        .style('background-color', 'orange');

    var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(a);

    rects.enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return i * 20; })
        .attr("width", "15px")
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d * 5; })
        .attr("data-currentVal", function (d) { return d });



    var updateData = function (newData: any) {
        rects.data(newData).transition().duration(2000)
            .attr("height", function (d: any) { return d * 5; })
            .attr("data-currentVal", function (d: any) { return d })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                if (d3.select(this).attr("data-currentVal") != d) {
                    return "red";
                }
                else { return "black"; }
            });
        console.log("updateData" + 1);
    }


    a[1] = 10;
    a[4] = 50;
    var enough = false;
    var repeatFunction = window.setInterval(function () {
        //console.log("repeat");
        updateData(a);

        a[3] = 20;
        a[1] = 15;

        if (enough) { window.clearInterval(repeatFunction); }
        else { enough = true; }

    }, 3000);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding the new data to your `rect` in `updateData`

https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#data

> Perhaps surprisingly, data is not a property of the selection, but a
>   property of its elements. This means that when you bind data to a
>   selection, the data is stored in the DOM rather than in the selection:
>   data is assigned to the **data** property of each element. If an
>   element lacks this property, the associated datum is undefined. Data
>   is therefore persistent while selections can be considered transient:
>   you can reselect elements from the DOM and they will retain whatever
>   data was previously bound to them.

The correct method is :

```
var updateData = function (newData: any) {
            svg.selectAll("rect").data(newData).transition().duration(2000)
                .attr("height", function (d: any) { return d * 5; })
                .attr("data-currentVal", function (d: any) { return d })
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    if (d3.select(this).attr("data-currentVal") != d) {
                        return "red";
                    }
                    else { return "black"; }
                });
            console.log("updateData" + 1);
        }
```